# re.sub python to gather height

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am writing a python program to parse some user data from a txt file. 
One of the rows in the text file will contain the user's height. 
I have specified an order that the user is expected to follow like

First line of the file should contain name, the next line, date of birth, 
3rd line, height etc.

I have also given a sample file to the user which looks like this

Name: First Name Last Name
DOB: 16.04.2000
Age: 16
Height: 5 feet 9 inch

When I read the file, I looked at each line and split it using ':' as a separator.

The first field is my column name like name, dob, age, height.

In some cases, users forget the ':' after Name or DOB, or they will simply send data like:

- Height 5 feet 9 inch
- 5 feet 9 inch
- 5ft 9 in
- 5feet 9inches

The logic I have decided to use is:

1. Look for ':' on each line; if one is found, then I have my field.
2. Otherwise, try to find out what data it could be.

The logic for height is like this:

```
if any(heightword in file_line.upper() for heightword in ['FT', 'HEIGHT', 'FEET', 'INCH', 'CM'])
```

This `if` condition will look for words associated with height.

Once I have determined that the line from the file contains the height, I want to be able to convert that information to inches before I write it to the database.

Please can someone help me work out how to convert the following data to inches.

- Height 5 feet 9 inch
- 5 feet 9 inch
- 5ft 9 in
- 5feet 9inches

I know since I am trying to cater to variety of user inputs. This list is not exhaustive; I am trying to use these as an example to understand, and then I will keep adding code if and when I find new patterns.

Comment: you can capture the numbers **[like](https://regex101.com/r/aD9nV5/1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, there is an operation called "computed access", done as `object[key]`, where the `object` property read is determined through the result of a given expression, as an alternative to the normal `.` operator. Personally, I mostly use it for iteration and reading properties with hyphens and stuff, but it can also be used to get associated wanted results from an input string.
So after an entire afternoon of Googling and figuring out Python syntax, etc. I was able to write a short program to do this.

```
import re
import string
h = 0
r = re.compile(r'(\d+)\s*(\w+)\b')
def incr( m ):
    h+=m.group(1)*({'in':1,'inches':1,'inch':1,'foot':12,'feet':12,'cm':0.3937,'centimeter':0.3937,'centimeters':0.3937}[string.lower(m.group(2))]||1) # etc. etc.
    return ''
re.sub(r, incr, input)
print h
```

You may want to restrict the keywords usable to keep the `dict` from getting too big.

Comment: thanks for this. I had used a similar dictionary in another program for conversion but in that one I was only getting user input in numbers so it was a simpler. will give this a try today

Answer (score 5):

pyparsing is a nice module for simple parsing situations like this, especially when trying to process less-than-predictable-but-still-fairly-structured human input. You can compose your parser using some friendly-named classes (`Keyword`, `Optional`, `OneOrMore`, and so on) and arithmetic operators (`'+'` for sequence, `'|'` for alternatives, etc.), to assemble smaller parsers into larger ones.  Here is a parser built up from bits for your example (also support ' and " for feet and inches, and fractional feet and inch values too). (This sample uses the latest version of pyparsing, version 2.1.4):

```
samples = """\
Height 5 feet 9 inch
5 feet 9 inch
5ft 9 in
5feet 9inches
5'-9-1/2"
5' 9-1/2"
5' 9 1/2"
6'
3/4"
3ft-6-1/4 in
"""


from pyparsing import CaselessKeyword, pyparsing_common, Optional

CK = CaselessKeyword
feet_units = CK("feet") | CK("ft") | "'"
inch_units = CK("inches") | CK("inch") | CK("in") | '"'

# pyparsing_common.number will parse an integer or real, and convert to float
integer = pyparsing_common.number

fraction = integer + '/' + integer
fraction.addParseAction(lambda t: t[0]/t[-1])

qty = fraction | (integer + Optional(fraction)).addParseAction(lambda t:sum(t))

# define whole Height feet-inches expression
HEIGHT = CK("height") | CK("ht")
inch_qty = qty("inches")
feet_qty = qty("feet")
height_parser = Optional(HEIGHT) + (inch_qty + inch_units | 
                                feet_qty + feet_units + Optional(inch_qty + inch_units))

# use parse-time callback to convert feet-and-inches to inches
height_parser.addParseAction(lambda t: t.get("feet", 0.0)*12 + t.get("inches", 0.0))

height_parser.ignore("-")

height_parser.runTests(samples)

# how to use the parser in normal code
height_value = height_parser.parseString(samples.splitlines()[0])[0]
print(height_value, type(height_value))
```

Prints:

```
Height 5 feet 9 inch
[69.0]


5 feet 9 inch
[69.0]


5ft 9 in
[69.0]


5feet 9inches
[69.0]


5'-9-1/2"
[69.5]


5' 9-1/2"
[69.5]


5' 9 1/2"
[69.5]


6'
[72.0]


3/4"
[0.75]


3ft-6-1/4 in
[42.25]

69.0 <type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out Stephen's code in the first comment on python 3.6 and had to tweak it to work for me:

```
import re
h = 0
input = '5 feet 9 inches'
r = re.compile(r'(\d)\s*(\w+)\b')
measures ={'in':1,'inches':1,'inch':1,'foot':12,'feet':12,'ft':12,'cm':0.3937,'centimeter':0.3937,'centimeters':0.3937}
def incr(m):
    global h
    h+=int(m.group(1))*measures[m.group(2)]
    return ''
re.sub(r, incr, input)
print(h)
```